# Limit Output in C

Tags: c

In C, I would like to limit the string to the first 8 characters. For example, I have:

```
char out = printf("%c", str);
```

How can I make it so it only returns the first 8 characters?

Comment: %c will only print one character.  I'd say you've already limited your output.

Answer (score 11):

You can limit the length by setting the precision in the format specifier:

```
printf("%.8s", str);
```

This will print *up to* eight characters from the null-terminated string pointed-to by `str`.  If the length of `str` is less than eight characters, then it will print the entire string.

Note that the format specifier for a null-terminated string is `%s`, not `%c` (`%c` is to print a single `char`), and that `printf` returns an `int` (the total number of characters printed), not a `char`.

Comment: Thanks dude. Is there a way to get rid of all the spaces?

Comment: Nvm. I've changed it to printf("%.s", hexencode(c)); Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can also specify the max length at runtime with the * specifier: `printf("%.*s", max_len, str);`

Answer (score 0):

No

That is incorrect.  tabular printing "%8s" pads up to say 8 spaces, as in the example given. It does not truncate.  ISOC99.  If this is a windows only thing, okay, MS ignores the world on lots of things.  If the length of the string is longer than the tabulation then the full string prints.  See:

```
int main()
{
  char tmp[]="123456789";
  printf("1  %1s\n", tmp);
  printf("2  %2s\n", tmp);
  printf("4  %4s\n", tmp);
  printf("8  %8s\n", tmp);
  printf("16 %16s\n", tmp);
  printf("32 %32s\n", tmp);
  return 0;
}
```

output from  gcc 3.4.2 on Solaris 5.9:

```
> ./a.out                   
1  123456789                       
2  123456789                       
4  123456789                       
8  123456789                       
16        123456789                
32                        123456789
```

sprintf() will duplicate and truncate a string then it can be sent to printf.  Or if you don't care about the source string:

```
char * trunc(char *src, int len)
{
    src[len]=0x0;
    return src;
}
```

References: INTERNATIONAL STANDARD ©ISO/IEC ISO/IEC 9899:TC2, WG14/N1124 Committee Draft — May 6, 2005

Comment: Assuming you meant this as a response to my answer, I believe you missed the `.` in the format specifier: `%8s` sets the *minimum* width to eight characters; `%.8s` sets the *maximum* width to eight characters (these are, respectively, the _width_ and _precision_ modifiers of the format specifier).  There is nothing platform-specific to this behavior--it's part of the specification of the C language (and C++, since it includes the C standard library).