# Set more characters than declared without any warning

Tags: c, gcc

I've reproduced it with simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char l1[16];

    sprintf(&l1, "%s", "Hello AKIT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    printf(l1);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Even my var is declared as 16 characters length, I can put in it much more characters without any errors from compiler, and it even works.
I'm expected that string will be cuted up to 16 characters but not. Why? And how I can get cutted string?

Comment: Undefined behavior means _anything_ can happen.

Comment: That's undefined behavior (different results on different platforms, and even during different executions on the same platform). What is actually a very well-defined behavior in this case (and not for a justifiable reason), is the fact that in a few seconds people are going to start downvoting your question for violating the sacred rule "shalt not do, say or imply anything that could potentially lead to undefined behavior".

Comment: this is called buffer overflow :) welcome in C programming

Comment: C does not enforce array/boundary limits like other languages do, so it's really up to the programmer to get these things right. This kind of thing happens *all the time* and requires a fair amount of diligence.

Comment: *"without any errors from compiller"* - that's because your compiler doesn't care whether your compiled code invokes undefined behavior or not: *you didn't care, it won't either.*.

Comment: Serhii, can you substitute "chapters" with "characters"? A chapter is a section in a book.

Comment: @MicheleDorigatti - You are also able to edit spelling or word choice in an original post if you choose.

Comment: Thanks to @SteveFriedl it is already edited. Thanks all of you guys, you are amazing community, I'm happy to be among you. My main language is php, and I have never problem like this before.

Comment: This is a FAQ ... where's the duplicate.

Comment: @WeatherVane Did not found any similar question while posting my own.

Comment: Here is: [Off by one error, but no segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521292/c-off-by-one-error-but-no-segmentation-fault) and there are others to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I can put in it much more characters without any errors from compiller...*

Your code has broken no syntax rules (except as noted in example below), so the compiler has no reason to complain.  However this:

```
char l1[16];

    //sprintf(&l1, "%s", "Hello AKIT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");  // & is wrong  l1 is already a pointer
                                                         // and should have resulted in 
                                                         // incompatible pointer type warning.

    sprintf(l1, "%s", "Hello AKIT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
```

...Is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This means that sometimes your program will appear to work, but at any time, it may cease to work. As written, you are overwriting the buffer.  But a C program will only complain at run-time, and then only if the memory you are writing to (and not owned by you) is owned by another process.  Then a run-time fault will occur.

Methods to prevent the buffer overflow problem (other than careful programming.) include learning about and using *[snsprintf()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/snprintf-c-library/)*.  There is also a *[length limiting format specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933404/645128)* that can be used with `sprintf()`.

Comment: @ryyker you can answer "And how I can get cutted string?": `snprintf` or `%15s`.

Comment: @LegendofPedro - Thank you.  I did incorporate your suggestion!

Comment: `Your code has broken no syntax rules` - but it easy to check, why gcc doesn't do that? Maybe there is some special flags for compiler to check this issue?

Comment: Try setting including `-Wall` in your [command line options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Option-Index.html#Option-Index) to include all errors and warnings.

Comment: `gcc -Wall -o main main.c` doesn't show me any additional warnings

Comment: @SerhiiPolishchuk -  I just tried on my gcc (in Code::Blocks, on Windows) and it produced the warning: `C:\...\main.c|8|warning: passing argument 1 of 'sprintf' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|`.  What version of gcc are you using?  (I am using 7.5)

Comment: @ryyker gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, but it doesn't matter anymore, because I have learned a lot about undefined behavior and buffer overflow. Thanks a lot!